# Pandas If Statements (excel equivalent)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, pandas

I'm trying to create a simple if statement in Pandas.

The excel version is as follows:

=IF(E2="ABC",C2,E2)

I'm stuck on how to assign it based on a string or partial string.

Here is what I have.

```
df['New Value'] = df['E'].map(lambda x: df['C'] if x == 'ABC' else df['E']]
```

I know I'm making a mistake here.

As the outcome is the entire dataframe values in each cell.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [36]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randn(5), 'B':0, 'C':np.arange(5),'D':1, 'E':['asdsa','ABC','DEF','ABC','DAS']})
df

Out[36]:
          A  B  C  D      E
0  0.831728  0  0  1  asdsa
1  0.734007  0  1  1    ABC
2 -1.032752  0  2  1    DEF
3  1.414198  0  3  1    ABC
4  1.042621  0  4  1    DAS

In [37]:    
df['New Value'] = np.where(df['E'] == 'ABC', df['C'], df['E'])
df

Out[37]:
          A  B  C  D      E New Value
0  0.831728  0  0  1  asdsa     asdsa
1  0.734007  0  1  1    ABC         1
2 -1.032752  0  2  1    DEF       DEF
3  1.414198  0  3  1    ABC         3
4  1.042621  0  4  1    DAS       DAS
```

The syntax for `np.where` is:

```
np.where( < condition >, True condition, False condition )
```

So when the condition is `True` it returns the True condition and when `False` the other condition.

Comment: Sorry just to add onto this. How do I get an or function in the string? eg. 'ABC' or 'CBA'?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question unless it's very minor

Comment: Use bitwise `|` operator : `np.where((df['E'] == 'ABC') | (df['E'] == 'CBA), df['C'], df['E'])`