# Panda adding column with if condition

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm not sure how to add a new column z to my existing df where z = x if x is not 0 else y .

For example:

```
Name  x  y  |z (new col)
A     1  5  |1
B     2  6  |2
C     0  3  |3
D     0  0  |0
```

Does np.where apply in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas If Statements (excel equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441551/pandas-if-statements-excel-equivalent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
 df['z'] = np.where(df['x']!=0,df['x'],df['y'])
```

Comment: I see.  "where" would be a an if then statement here.  Thanks